# Prove $2^{a} + 2^{b} \neq 2^{c}, \ \ \forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{Z}^{\geqslant0} \ \ (a \neq b \neq c)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My approach is if $a > b$, we can write $2^{a} + 2^{b}$ as $2^{b} (1 + 2^{a - b})$.

$2^b$ is clearly an even number, and $1 + 2^{a - b}$ is an odd number. Their product will be an even number, and that is the case for $2^c$.

If $a < b$, we can write $2^{a} + 2^{b}$ as $2^{a} (1 + 2^{b - a})$. $2^a$ and $1 + 2^{b-a}$ are even and odd numbers, respectively, and their product is even, which is the case for $2^c$.

What should I do next?

Comment: Hint: $2^n+1$ is odd. What can you factor to get to this ?

Comment: Show you have worked...

Comment: Hello :) What have you tried on your own? W.l.o.g. assume $a<b$ then $2^a+2^b=2^a(1+2^{b-a})$. What do you know about $1+2^{b-a}$ if $a<b$?

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for your comment. I'll update the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WLOG assume assume that $a < b < c$. Therefore, the equation becomes $2^a(1 + 2^{b - a}) = 2^c$. This simplifies to $1 + 2^{b - a} = \frac{2^c}{2^a} = 2^{c - a}$. The RHS is a power of $2$ which makes it even, but the LHS is odd because it is $1$ plus a power of $2$. Therefore, the LHS cannot equal the RHS.

Comment: This question lacks context (and was closed for that reason).  In the future, please try to help the asker to improve their question before you provide an answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson thanks.